# summing all elements in matlab without using colon operator

Tags: matlab

I want to sum all elements of matrix in Matlab. If I had a matrix called A, then I can sum all elements by calling

```
sum(A(:));
```

But I would like to sum elements returning from a function like this:

```
sum(gammaln(A))  % where gammaln is the logarithm of gamma function
```

Of course I can do this in two steps:

```
B = gammaln(A);
sum(B(:));
```

But here I create a B matrix, which I don't need at all. And also I can do it this way:

```
sum(sum(gammaln(A)))
```

But, the number of sum's will be equal to the dimension of my matrix. It looks ugly, and the matrix dimension may change.

I'm curious if there is any way of doing this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use `reshape` instead of `(:)` operator:

```
sum(reshape(gammaln(A),[],1))
```